# Apparently "npm install -g" not working as a global library

Tags: node.js, npm

To use a node library (uuid) as a command line tool from an other software I'm working on, I installed the library globally by `npm i --global uuid` and tested the installation by `node -e 'console.log(require("uuid")())'`, but I get an error `Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'`, the global installation apparently not working properly. If I save the library locally, on the directory run the same command, it does work, so the problem is apparently the global installation. What's wrong with this?

```
$ nvm --version
0.35.3
$ npm -v
6.13.7
$ node -v
v13.10.1
```

Comment: Note: I couldn't use the "uuid" library from the command line evaluate using the globally installed path, but using a locally installed path. so like, `cd path/to/a/dir ; export NODE_PATH="$(npm root )"` rather than `export NODE_PATH="$(npm root -g)"`.  I assume it's most probably because the particular package "uuid" is different between the versions and/or the installation method, globally or locally.

Answer (score -1):

here is an ref , it can be access rights on mac/linux

https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/main/npm-global-without-sudo.md